# Mounting a remote share (why do I supply a local path?)

Tags: mount, raspberry-pi, path, rsyslog, shared-folders

I have zero previous experience with unix (other than I used to have an account on an SGI box more than 25 years ago and remember some of the commands).

I want a rasberry pi 4 to auto-logon to a remote share (could be a NAS box, could be a windows share) and the mount command specifies the remote path and also specifies a local path which must exist.

I don't understand why.

What role does the local path perform?

I want the PI to act as a syslog server and write the logs to the remote share.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Unix/Linux tries to represent everything as a file/directory in the local filesystem (even things like hardware and states of the system).

So this also counts for remote directories:
After mounting a remote dir on a local dir you will be able to read/write from/to the local dir but the effects will actually happen on the remote dir.

It also makes it way easier for software to handle files on remote servers because it can use them as if they exist locally.

Example: In my `/etc/fstab` file (the file containing all information about how the system should mount stuff) on my desktop I have a line:

`//secrethostname/vanalles /mnt/targasmb cifs user,noauto,guest,ro 0  0`

(`secrethostname` is actually another name, i just don't want to post it online...)

When I now run `mount /mnt/targasmb` on my desktop I will be able to see all files in the `vanalles` dir on `secrethostname` in the directory `/mnt/targasmb` on my local system. I will also be able to able to read them as if they exist locally.

`cifs user,noauto,guest,ro 0  0` provides the system more info about what the mount is and how it should be mounted by default. The details are for another question.

Comment: I guess I find it strange that I have to specify a local (and real) dir to which nothing actually gets written to when I mount (and write to) the remote dir.  I could understand this better if the local dir was virtual (for the purpose of the mount) and hence would go away when the remote dir was unmounted.  The current implimentation makes it confusing when you issue a dir listing command and you don't know what files actually do exist in the local dir vs which ones exist on the remote share.

Comment: Or what happens if files with the same names already exist in both locations when the mount command is issued.

Comment: If there are already files in the local dir they become invisible until you `umount` the remote dir (this is why you normally do this on a empty dir). Because the local files become invisible the problem of files with the same name doesn't occur. There are implementations that do it like you describe (creating a temporary dir before mounting and removing after mounting) but they are very rare because it makes things harder(e.g. user has to start searching for the dir). It is possible to write scripts that do this for you, but the system that doesn't do it automatically to give you more control

Comment: Ok, so this is a really kludgy way they decided to do this.  Not elegant at all.

Comment: I wouldn't have it any other way. Lot's of advantages and the only thing vaguely resembling a disadvantage is that you have to choose a local location. "have to" should even be replaced by "get to".

Comment: I'm used to windows networking and when you want to access a shared folder on another machine you just do it and the remote path becomes your share or you can map a network drive.  Having to make the remote dir masquerade as a pre-existing local dir is weird.

Comment: That is how (computer) science works. A lot of things are "weird" but that doesn't make them bad, in most cases it's even better. You'll probably want to know that "under the hood' windows does the same thing.  Also, nemo (and similar linuxsoftware) allow the user to use the "windows way" (even with extra support for ftp, scp, and other protocols). The main difference is that windows makes it really hard to use the unix-way. Still, this is not the recommend way of working.